# hasManyThrough with a belongsToMany?

Tags: laravel

A `Producer` `hasOne` `Distillery`, a `Distillery` `belongsToMany` `Whiskies`.

A `Whisky` `belongsToMany` `Distillery`, a `Distillery` `belongsTo` `Producer`.

I wish to use `hasManyThrough` so, to get a  `Producer`'s `Whiskies` that `belongToMany` `Distillery`.

But how can I use `hasManyThrough` with `belongsToMany` relationship? I am aware you can specify the join keys, and I think you may be able to muck about with the pivot table, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `hasManyThrough` does not directly support your scenario.

However, you can achieve your goal by manually defining a custom method in your `Producer` model to retrieve the `whiskies` through `distilleries`.

```
class Producer extends Model
{
    public function whiskies()
    {
        return Whisky::whereHas('distilleries', function ($query) {
            $query->where('producer_id', $this->id);
        });
    }
}
```

Also define the inverse relationship in your `Whisky` model to get the `producer`

```
class Whisky extends Model
{
    public function producer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Producer::class, 'producer_id');
    }
}
```

Now you can retrieve a producer's whiskies like this:

```
$producer = Producer::find($producerId);
$whiskies = $producer->whiskies;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you relationships shoul look like this:

```
// Producer model
public function distillery()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Distillery::class);
}

// Distillery model
public function producer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Producer::class);
}

public function whiskies()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Whisky::class);
}

// Whisky model
public function distilleries()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Distillery::class);
}
```

To get the whiskies of a producer through a distillery, you can't use hasManyThrough directly. Instead, you can define a custom method:

```
// In the Producer model

public function whiskies()
{
    $distillery = $this->distillery;

    if($distillery) {
        return $distillery->whiskies;
    }

    return collect(); // empty collection if no distillery
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a fantastic package that makes this easy: [eloquent-has-many-deep](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep)

With that package creating a function like that is as easy as:

```php
use HasRelationships;

public function whiskies(): HasManyDeep
{
    return $this->hasManyDeepFromRelations($this->distillery(), (new Distillery)->whiskies());
}
```